# View History of all solutions, instead of inside every solution?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Using the Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) at `http://foo.visualstudio.com`, is found a list of all solutions (or projects) using browse (or 'Browse Server' dialog).  We have over 50 solutions on there.

I found it to be such a pain to browse through each of the over 50 solutions to find the `History` (or commit histories).

Is there a way to use `History` (or commit histories) for all solutions in one result listing?

Comment: Do you mean Team Projects?

Comment: Do you check my answer? Does it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The View History feature is running in the Team Project Collection context so you can't visualize the history of all collections in one view.

As an workaround you can move your Team Projects content in one Team Project Collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git:

If solutions/projects are in the same repository, you can retrieve histories in Code=>History page or git commits REST API (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits).

Otherwise, you could build an application with git commits REST API to retrieve each repository separately and combine the results.

If you are using TFVC:

You could retrieve all items history in a collection in source control explorer (right click the root level=>history), you also could get list of changesets by using REST API (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets).